# How to debug my Xdebug - step over not working

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2, php-7.4

I created a simple unit test like the following

```php
public function testX()
{
    $x = 1;

    $this->assertEquals(1, $x);
}
```

- I set a breakpoint on the assert line
- I click debug
- Debugger stops on the correct line
- I click step over
- Debugger stops in `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php` somewhere (specifically for PHPUnit 7.5.20 - 2020-01-08 on line 1199 `if ($this->expectedException !== null)`)  in the `runTest` method.
- Continuing to debug until the end returns the error message `This test did not perform any assertions` and the test fails.

Context:

- WSL2
- Xdebug 3 config found in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

  ```ini
  xdebug.mode=debug,develop,coverage,gcstats,profile,trace
  #xdebug.mode=debug
  xdebug.client_host=172.21.96.1
  xdebug.client_port=9001
  xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
  xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
  #xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
  xdebug.start_with_request=yes
  ```
- PhpStorm installed on Windows - debugger configuration is all green.

To add salt to wound, if I run the test instead of debugging, the test passes.

To sum up, I can debug 1 single line from my tests.

Any ideas of what to check ?

Comment: Are you debugging a remote site? Are you sure that remote contents are matching local? I've just run the same locally and it worked fine here. Btw, are you on latest PhpStorm?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitrii, it's local repo, using WSL2.

Comment: Try using PHPUnit 9 perhaps - would that work any different?